# Find the area of shade region in a triangle with several small triangles inside

Tags: triangles

In the picture, the big triangle is equilateral an has area 9. The lines are parallel to the sides and divide the sides into three equal parts. What is the area of the shaded part?

[image]

This is a question from a math competition

I'm getting the answer of 6, but the answer given in answer sheet is 7.

Could anyone please explain the method to get 7?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The answer is indeed $6$.

Comment: oh.. so the answer sheet is wrong. Thank you so much!!